# Check if two URL strings are equal

Tags: javascript, constants, string-comparison

I'm building out a function to handle dynamic phone number swapping, identifying the `referral` url, mapping through a data set, and then outputting the `promoUrl`'s related phone number. The data is formatted like this:

```
const phoneNumbers = [
  {
    promoUrl: '/interior-doors/',
    promoNumber: '589-918-0710',
  },
  {
    promoUrl: '/promo4/',
    promoNumber: '307-789-8615',
  },
];
```

And the function maps through the data and reduces it, allowing me to sort through it like this:

```
const url = location.pathname.replace(/\/+$/, '');

const promoNumber = phoneNumbers.reduce((promoNumber, results) => {
  const hasPromo = results.promoUrl.includes(url);

  if (hasPromo) {
    return results.promoNumber;
  }
    return promoNumber;
}, '');
```

I'm having some issues with `hasPromo`. The way it's built right now allows for the promoUrl to have some variance and still work, meaning as long as it includes what is returned from `url` then it works i.e. `/interior-doors/`, `/interior-doors`, and `interior-doors` will all work, which is great, but it also works if `url` is `/interior-do`. I need it to not do that. It should work independent of formatting, but only return the `promoNumber` if the string of letters is exact.

I'm assuming this is a `regex` thing, but I don't know what I'm doing with `regex`. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `==` to do an exact match. And since the `promoURL` property always has `/` around it, add those delimiters when you set `url`

```
const url = '/' + location.pathname.replace(/\/+$/, '') + '/';

const promoNumber = phoneNumbers.reduce((promoNumber, results) => {
  const hasPromo = results.promoUrl == url;

  if (hasPromo) {
    return results.promoNumber;
  }
  return promoNumber;
}, '');
```

`reduce` also seems like the wrong function for this. You just need to find the matching `promoUrl`, you don't have to continue reducing, since the reduction function doesn't merge the results in any way.

```
const promo = phoneNumbers.find(({promoUrl}) => promoUrl == url);
const promoNumber = promo ? promo.promoNumber : '';
```

Comment: Amazing, this is perfect. Thank you so much, saves so much code.

Comment: Quick clarifying question: I still need this to work if the `promoUrl` doesn't have both `/` around it; once the site is live, the creation of the `promoUrl`s will not be devs, and I'd rather have it be foolproof. Is that possible?

Comment: It would be best if the tool you give the non-devs ensures that it creates them in a consistent format.

Comment: You could use `results.promoUrl == url || results.promoUrl == '/' + url + '/'` to handle both formats.

Comment: In place of `results.promoUrl == url`. And then you don't add the `/` when initializing `url`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant this chunk: 


`const promo = phoneNumbers.find(({promoUrl}) => promoUrl == url);`

`const promoNumber = promo ? promo.promoNumber : '';`

Comment: `promoUrl == url` is replaced with `promoUrl == url || promoUrl == '/' + url + '/'` Isn't it obvious?

Comment: I'd written it up here as you responded, although it would be `promoUrl == url || '/' + url + '/'`. Thanks again.